# Python: process average timing, first one/two are much slower

Tags: python, performance, timer, pypy

I'm writing some program with sorting algorithms comparsion using Python. I want to measure average sorting time. I have a problem with first measurement.

This:

```
for i in xrange(self.repeats):
    # random list generator
    data_orig = [random.randint(0, self.size - 1) for x in xrange(self.size)]

    sorter = self.class_()
    data = data_orig[:]
    debug("%s for data size: %d, try #%d" % (sorter.__class__.__name__, self.size, i+1))
    t1 = time.clock()
    sorter.sort(data)
    t2 = time.clock()
    debug("Took: %0.4fms, shifts: %d, comparisons: %d" % ((t2-t1)*1000.0, sorter.shifts, sorter.comps))
```

`class_` is a reference to InsertionSort class.
For size = 1000 and 5 repeats I get following results:

```
InsertionSort for data size: 1000, try #1
Took: 39.5341ms, shifts: 254340, comparisons: 255331
InsertionSort for data size: 1000, try #2
Took: 6.0765ms, shifts: 250778, comparisons: 251772
InsertionSort for data size: 1000, try #3
Took: 6.9946ms, shifts: 254189, comparisons: 255180
InsertionSort for data size: 1000, try #4
Took: 6.7421ms, shifts: 252162, comparisons: 253156
InsertionSort for data size: 1000, try #5
Took: 5.9584ms, shifts: 241412, comparisons: 242404
```

For every sorting algorithm and every time I run program first result is bigger than the others. I run it with PyPy (with Python it seems OK, but it's MUCH slower).

I know I can simply ommit first results but this solution doesn't satisfies me :-)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's the whole point of PyPy. It's an optimizing just-in-time compiler, which means that the more you run a piece of code, the more optimized it gets. The first time you run it, it hasn't had a chance to do any optimization, so the result will be slow. Subsequent runs will take into account the lessons learned from the first time, so will be faster.

Comment: This. From http://pypy.org/performance.html: **In general, make sure you warm up your program before running benchmarks, if you're measuring something long-running like a server**

Comment: It's worth noting that even in CPython it's going to be _somewhat_ slower the first time, because there's stuff that gets loaded into disk cache, maybe even .py files getting compiled into .pyc files, etc. The idea of "warm up before benchmarking" is _always_ necessary. The fact that PyPy makes it more _obviously_ necessary should probably be counted as a bonus benefit.

Comment: So basically it's a good idea to ommit first two measurements or are there any better solutions to warm up my program? I care about results.